# Using dynamic number of sliders with ipywidgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to call a function interactively using `ipywidgets` with a dynamic number of sliders.
I am able to display it.

```py
n_alphas = 3
alphas = [
    widgets.FloatSlider(min=-1, max=1, step=1e-3, description=f'$z_{i}$', orientation='vertical')
    for i in range(n_alphas)
]
ui = widgets.HBox(alphas)
display(ui)
```

This correctly renders three vertical sliders as defined by `n_alphas`.

[image: three vertical sliders]

Unfortunately I am not able to bind this UI with the dynamic number of sliders to some function.
I tried variants of the following, but nothing worked:

```py
out = widgets.interactive_output(print_alphas, alphas)
display(ui, out)
```

What is needed to bind the list of sliders defined by `alphas` to the function `print_alphas` and how should that function itself be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest individually [monitoring](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html#Traitlet-events) the sliders an accessing all alphas from within that monitor function:

```
# monitor function, reporting both the changed value and all other values
def handle_slider_change(change):
    values = [alpha.value for alpha in alphas]
    caption.value = (
        f'The slider {change.owner.description} has a value of {change.new}. '
        f'The values of all sliders are {values}'
    )

# create sliders
n_alphas = 3
alphas = [
    widgets.FloatSlider(min=-1, max=1, step=1e-3, description=f'$z_{i}$', orientation='vertical')
    for i in range(n_alphas)
]
# register slides
for widget in alphas:
    widget.observe(handle_slider_change, names='value')

# display ui
ui = widgets.HBox(alphas)
caption = widgets.Label(value='No change was made yet.')
display(caption, ui)
```

Comment: Thanks, works as intended. For everyone wondering how to integrate this with an interactive `matplotlib` plot, there is `%matplotlib widget`, and most plot types support functions like `set_data` that allow for fast updates of earlier established plots.